# Using the icu library, an undefined reference to 'uregex_groupCount_48' appears when compiling with make

Tags: compiler-errors, undefined-reference, autoconf, automake, icu

icu version : 4.8.1
use autoconf and automake to compile
Use dynamic library：LDFLAGS= -licui18n -licuuc -licudata
add header files：-I${ICU_ROOT}/unicode/include

${ICU_ROOT} is the file path where I use ./configure --prefix=..... to store the icu compilation.

I use uregex_groupCount function in my project，When I compile it appears  undefined reference to 'uregex_groupCount_48' .Then I found that in urename.h file there is macro about function name substitution.

For example: #define uregex_groupCount U_ICU_ENTRY_POINT_RENAME(uregex_groupCount)
U_ICU_ENTRY_POINT_RENAME(x) x ## _48

So the function name in the final project is replaced with a name with a _48 suffix.I want to know how to solve this problem.